# Customize Resharper Marker Bar

Tags: colors, themes, highlighting, resharper

Is it possible to change the colour of the TODO/NotImplementedExceptions in the Resharper Marker Bar?

I find the cyan nearly impossible to see on the grey backround of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done.  Just found an msg about it on the JetBrains website

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5270172;jsessionid=149398819F7C1926CFF1D9FDB528C8C5

Which led me to the issue, where I have voted for it, hopefully this is added in the future

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-44687

Answer (score 0):

Go to **`Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display items:`**

There you will find a lot of Resharper items for which you can change colors.

There is "Resharper TODO Items" also.

Comment: that only changes the text in the editor, I'm talking about the Marker Bar to the right of the code that has the red, green, orange, etc lines. indicating lines that require some form of attention.